# Get HTML Source with Values attributes set for Input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm using jQuery to send an HTML document which contains a form to a C# WebService.
The webService parse it and try to read "value" attribute of all inputs in the form.

The problem is that I send the HTML doc to the webservice with

```
var HTMLDoc = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
```

And it does not returns the input with value attribute.
For example, I got a :

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```

And I want the JavaScript to get :

```
<input type="text" id="foo" value="bar" />
```

when I do something like

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
```

Is this possible ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it

## HTML

```
<input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
```

in Jquery :

```
var foo = $("#foo").val();
alert("Jquery foo value : " + foo);
```

in JavaScript :

```
var foo = document.foo.value;
alert("JavaScript foo value : " + foo);
```

Comment: Thank's but The problem is that I send to the WebService all the form (I send document.getElementById('FORM').innerHTML;) and there is 180 inputs into. I can't make 180 val()

Comment: $("id").find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
//code 
});
you can get all input text

Comment: $("id").find('input[type=text]').each(function(index){
     alert("value : " + $(this).val());
});

you can get all input text value ..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('foo').outerHTML
```