# Get HTML with current input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the HTML of the whole page, with the current values of all inputs in their `value="..."`.

I've tried this:

```
document.getElementById("htmlId").innerHTML;
```

and this:

```
$('html').html();
```

but the both return the HTML page but without the input values.

<sub>I know that this looks like [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585877/get-html-source-with-values-attributes-set-for-input), but it is not the same. I really need get the HTML *with the value attributes*.</sub>

Comment: May be my english is not good !but  what you need ?  when is try "document.getElementById("html").innerHTML;" i was get the value of  html tag

Comment: `$('#html').html();` needs `#` to identify as ID..add html mark up to see the problem

Comment: `.html()` or `innerHTML` will return the markup. Value is a property associated with input elements. Yes you have a tag, but eventually you end you initiating this property. So when you change value dynamically, it updates property and not attribute

Comment: @guradio No. `#` means element with ID. `$(html)` means root node, html tag element

Comment: @Rajesh in OP there is `document.getElementById("html")` meaning the element has ID html and not the root html. unless html is added we can only guess for now

Comment: @guradio Even I though that, but as OP has stated, *I need to get the whole html page with the values.*, that implies he  is using incorrect method

Comment: Mention what are you going to do with that HTML as part of question. That may help others coming up with solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An input has a [`value` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value) that determines the *initial* value of the input. It also has a [`value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) that holds the *current* value of the input.

It appears that you want to export the HTML markup of the page, where the `value` attributes of all inputs are set to the value of the `value` property.

You can do so as follows:

```
// first, set `value` attribute to value of property for all inputs
$('input').attr('value', function() {
  return $(this).val();
});
// export HTML with correct `value` attributes
$('html').html();
```

And here is a little demo of that in action.

```js
$('#export').on('click', () => {
  $('input').attr('value', function() {
    return $(this).val();
  });
  console.log($('html').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some paragraph.</p>
<input type="text" value="initial value" />
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
<button id="export">Export page</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**for input value inside html use this code may got some help**

```
$("#html input[type=text]").each(function(index,value) {     
    val = $("#"+value.id).val();
    alert(val)   
});
```

Comment: *I need to get the whole html page with the values* I don't think OP is looking for this

Comment: apply selector type and get values by class or id and use them out of loop

Comment: This gets only the values, I need the html with values inside the html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "*html*" itself is an id of an element, you can try cloneNode.

```
var clonedElem = document.getElementById("html").cloneNode(true);
```

This `clonedElem` is a DOM object which contains both html as well as values ( and all other attributes). You can now use this DOM for all your purposes.

For Eg. If you wish to insert it into another element, you can do like

```
document.getElementById('newElement').appendChild(clonedElem)
```

This will put the entire node with its values

Answer (score 1):

As commented before,

> `.html()` or `innerHTML` will return the markup. `value` is a property associated with *input* elements. Yes you have a tag, but eventually you end you initiating this property. So when you change value dynamically, it updates property and not attribute

You will have to loop over all the inputs and set `value` attribute.

```js
function updateAttribute() {
  var parent = document.querySelector(".content");
  var inputs = parent.querySelectorAll("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].setAttribute("value", inputs[i].value);
  }
}
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/k10x80zu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get input values I will do with `.attr` to change dynamically element value !

```
$("ButtonToCatchInputValue").click(function(){
        $("input").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("value",this.value);
        });
        console.log($("html").html());  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.cloneNode` to clone the whole document with **retaining** the state of the html.

> cloneNode has a boolean parameter that denotes the following
>
> true - Clone the node, its attributes, and its descendants
>
> false - Default. Clone only the node and its attributes

For more details check this [document](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)

```js
function cloneMe() {
  var newelement = document.cloneNode(true);
  console.log(newelement.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Change My Value" style="width:100%" />
<input type="submit" onclick="cloneMe()" value="Clone Now" />
```

Comment: This copies the property, but when you export the `innerHTML` you'll see that the attribute is still `Change My Value`.

Comment: you should not use it as innerHTML. You should use `appendChild` to have the exact state of the html

Comment: The question is about having it in the exported HTML.