# Iterate through a table and get the value in asp.net core using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to iterate through a table to get the input value. How can I do that ?

tried looping and iterating over the tr and class names. console.log showing nothing for the moment.

CSHTML

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PositionDebit)
        </td>
        <td class="Debit">
            <span>@item.Debits</span>
            <input class="Debits" type="number" value="@item.Debits" />
        </td>
        <td class="CoefPonderation">
            <span>@item.CoefficientDePonderation</span>
            <input class="CoefPonderation" type="number" value="@item.CoefficientDePonderation" />
        </td>
        <td class="Jauge">
            <span>@item.Jauge</span>
            <input class="Jauge" type="number" value="@item.Jauge" />
        </td>

    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Javascript
The id of the table is tblDebit

```
  $("#tblDebit tr").each(function () {
        var debit = {};
        debit.Debits = $(this).find(".Debits").html();
        debit.CoefPonderation = $(this).find(".CoefPonderation").html();
        debit.Jauge = $(this).find(".Jauge").html();
        console.log(debit.Debits);
        console.log(debit.CoefPonderation);
        alert(debit.CoefPonderation);
        debits.push(debit);
    });
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with c# - it looks like a jQuery/Javascript only issue. If so, please add a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML instead of templating

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: And use .val() instead of .html() for input fields

Comment: Is debits an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML with current input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451448/get-html-with-current-input-values)

Comment: @mplungjan yes, Debit is an array. thanks for your help

Comment: Feel free to delete the question, it is not useful for anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have some issues here:

1. First use .val() instead of .html().
2. you should use the class CoefPonderation in your td or input not both.
3. in your loop get each element and dont use this.

here is the javascript code:

```js
$("#tblDebit").find("tbody").children("tr").each(function(index, element) {
  let debits = [],
    debit = {};
  debit.Debits = $(element).find(".Debits").val();
  debit.CoefPonderation = $(element).find(".CoefPonderation").children('input[type="number"]').val();
  debit.Jauge = $(element).find(".Jauge").val();
//  console.log(debit.Debits);
//  console.log(debit.CoefPonderation);
  console.log('row:' + $.trim($(element).find("td").first().text()) + ', debit:' + debit.Debits + ', ponderation:' + debit.CoefPonderation);
  debits.push(debit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblDebit" border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>row</th>
    <th>Debits</th>
    <th>Ponderation</th>
    <th>Jauge</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td class="Debit">
        <span>item 1</span>
        <input class="Debits" type="number" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="CoefPonderation">
        <span>ponderation 1</span>
        <input class="CoefPonderation" type="number" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="Jauge">
        <span>Jauge 1</span>
        <input class="Jauge" type="number" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td class="Debit">
        <span>item 2</span>
        <input class="Debits" type="number" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td class="CoefPonderation">
        <span>ponderation 2</span>
        <input class="CoefPonderation" type="number" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td class="Jauge">
        <span>Jauge 2</span>
        <input class="Jauge" type="number" value="2" />
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of html() use val()

```
    debit.Debits = $(this).find(".Debits").val();
    debit.CoefPonderation = $(this).find(".CoefPonderation").val();
    debit.Jauge = $(this).find(".Jauge").val();
```

Comment: So actually a typo-type question - perhaps close it as such?

Comment: We see questions confusing `.html()` and `.val()` at least once a day. Please don't answer duplicates.